# PDO vs MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Но чем PDO лучше mysqli?

```
$db -> query ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'");
while ($row = $db -> fetch_row()) {
 //do smth;
}
```

Получается абсолютно то же самое.

Comment: А http://google.ru пробовали?

Comment: > Получается абсолютно то же самое.

Заранее оговорюсь, что понимаю в чем состоит вопрос, но сейчас он эквивалентен такому:

> Я написал программу, которая выводит время на компе, программу, которая запрашивает время по ntp и программу, которая выводит текущее время компьютера в любом формате. Однако если я запрашиваю, сколько сейчас секунд, выводится одно и то же!

Смысл PDO в

* удобстве и предсказуемости работы
* совместимости - большинство кода будет работать одинаково для всех БД
* автоматизации процессов типа экранирования и prepared statements
* дополнительных функциях

Comment: PDO не лучше mysqli - они немного разные, в mysqli есть немного сахара специфичного для mysql, в PDO есть куча сахара неспецифичного для mysql но общего для всех sql баз данных. вы же используете что PDO что mysqli неправильно. Без bind вы делаете тоже самое что и пользователи php-mysql, а именно -  подвергаете себя опасности sql inject.